# Can't Install TOR on Ubuntu Netbook 10.10

Tags: installation, ubuntu-netbook, tor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)

I downloaded the tar.gz file from TORproject .org and unzipped it. I clicked everything inside the directories but nothing happened. I also tried to install the addon from [Mozilla Addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/torbutton/). The addon is installed but I can't see the TOR button anywhere. I checked relevant the option in the preferences section of tools>addons.

How do I install it?

Command:

```
gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring \
 /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt \
 /trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver \
 keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 886DDD89
```

Output:

```
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 886DDD89: public key "deb.torproject.org archive signing key" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or he COULD just add the Lucid repository...

```
echo "deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org experimental-lucid main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 886DDD89
```

Still running Tor/Vidalia from there with no problem.

Comment: Can you please explain me how do I add a Lucid repository? I guess by typing this in the terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Installing from a source tar.gz requires more skills, you should install the package from the repositories instead: http://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

Comment: Would you kindly direct me to someplace where I can learn how to install from a source tar.gz. Should I ask a different question for this? I tried to find if this has been asked previously, but couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: It should be a different question, I guess it was asked already.