# Anonymous Internet browsing

Tags: internet, software-recommendation

Could you please suggest me a good anonymous internet browsing application for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does private browsing mode in chromium/firefox count?

Comment: Hi dv3500ea, I am looking for somehting like the TOR network. Which masks your IP with Proxy servers IP.

Comment: Something like Tor? So why not Tor?

Comment: No I can  use TOR, I just wanted to get an opinion from you guys. Maybe I was missing something good :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Tor** is one of the best tools for anonymity on the internet. The most common way today is to use Tor is the Tor browser bundle, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420247/158442) for more. You can use Tor without a proxy server, although the Tor project suggests using a proxy for better performance.

#### Installing Tor

Using any method, edit your repositories and add the Tor repository. See also [detailed instructions for installing Tor from the Tor project](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en).

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
```

Replace `trusty` with the codename for your release (check the output of `lsb_release -sc`). Make sure Universe and Multiverse Repositories are enabled.

Add the Tor GPG key:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update repositories and install Tor:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

Install Privoxy:

```
sudo apt-get install privoxy
```

**Some GUI for Tor:**

- [Vidalia](http://www.torproject.org/projects/vidalia.html.en) is a graphical config tool.
- [Tor Browser](http://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser) can run off  from a thumb drive without needing to install any software.

**Note:**
Privoxy is optional. It is a proxy and it offers additional features including adblocking. The advantages of privoxy include built in adblock.

- [Tor FAQ](http://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#HowUninstallTor)
- [Privoxy FAQ](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/)

Comment: Thanks Karthick, I have used TOR on windows, didnt know its the best for Ubuntu as well. Any other solutions?

Comment: Kathick, Whats privoxy?

Comment: i gave you the +1 but please edit your answer to reflect adding to repositories...kthx...the gist is right though

Comment: @karthick87: Tor is no longer in Ubuntu repositories -- it's necessary to add repository from torproject.org as mentioned here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor

Comment: `@Vojtech Trefny:` I have updated.

Comment: @t3ch Privoxy is an HTTP proxy that sits in front of Tor and strips out a lot of potentially-identifying information.  Polipo is another alternative that may be preferred these days.  Tor is preferred for pretty much any platform; everyone using Tor helps Tor's ability to anonymize.  You might also consider installing Vidalia, a GUI for starting and controlling Tor.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor

Comment: Torbutton is no longer supported. In alternative Tor developers recommend the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html).

Answer (score 3):

One easy, effective way to anonymously browse The Internet is by using the **[Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)** which is partially based on Mozilla Firefox ESR.

### Download Tor Browser Bundle

- From [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), select your Language and download the 32-bit or 64-bit flavor as well as the accompanying sig file to ~/path/to/TBB_directory.

[image]

### Verify GPG Signature

- Download Erinn Clark's key ([as she signs Tor Browser Bundle packages](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en)):

  ```
  gpg --recv-keys 0x416F061063FEE659
  ```
- Verify that the signature file was produced when Erinn's key signed your Tor Browser Bundle download (adjust commands if version is not 3.5.2 or Language is not "en"):

  ```
  cd ~/path/to/TBB_directory 
  gpg --verify tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2_en-US.tar.xz
  ```
- You should see "Good signature.." in your terminal if successful (if not, download file again and try once more):

  ```
  gpg: Signature made Sun 09 Feb 2014 01:19:13 AM EST
  gpg:                using RSA key 0x416F061063FEE659
  gpg: Good signature from "Erinn Clark <erinn@torproject.org>" [unknown]
  gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@debian.org>" [unknown]
  gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@double-helix.org>" [unknown]
  gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
  gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
  Primary key fingerprint: 8738 A680 B84B 3031 A630  F2DB 416F 0610 63FE E659
  ```

### Extract Tor Browser Bundle Package

- Right-click `tar.xz` file and select "Extract Here" or:

  ```
  tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2_en.tar.xz
  ```

### Browse The Internet using globally distributed, encrypted, and anonymous Tor network

- Open newly extracted directory and double-click `start-tor-browser` or:

  ```
  ./start-tor-browser
  ```
- Select `Run` if Ubuntu asks you how you want to execute the `start-tor-browser' script.

Congratulations!

Comment: But how to download `*.asc` file needed for  `gpg --verify` ?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has basic support of "anonymous" browsing -- but that means only not storing history, cache and cookies. For "real anonymity" is best solution Tor:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor

Comment: Any options like TOR?

Comment: @t3ch: I think there isn't another service like Tor -- you can try to use some proxy servers but the free ones are wery slow and paid aren't cheap...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Tor works without problems on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome or Chromium you can also use the following [extensions](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/11/01/15-google-chrome-extensions-for-better-privacy-control/). I'm using them and they look alright. The only problem is that it makes browsing the internet a bit slow.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the "FoxyProxy" plugin, and some anonymous proxy action... that'd give you the same effect.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? FoxyProxy is a plugin for what browser? What does it do?