# Anonymous internet browsing (2017)

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, internet

This question was last answered 6 years ago: [Anonymous Internet browsing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16086/anonymous-internet-browsing).

What has changed? [Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) suggests not using Tor for Ubuntu. I'm running a 16.04 LTE. Is there any way to browse the internet anonymously for free? Are PrivateBrowser and Anonymox any good?

Comment: Could you provide the reference links that you've investigated to the moment.

Comment: Your question is quite broad. The TOR website is IMO the place to start. Use the TOR bundle, read the TOR documentation, and if you have a specific question about ubuntu ask a specific question.

Comment: Give me a sec, I'll edit the question

Comment: funny how the Tor website suggest not using the repositories provided bundles, but they them self not supporting the STS releases of Ubuntu. Only the LTS releases. webupd8teams ppa as well has its newest version compiled 34 weeks ago https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser

Comment: @Angler_phish you should read the statement on the Tor site itself again, they provide a version for xenial xerus and just say to dont use the Tor-Browser from the ubuntu repositorys. They not state that you should not use tor at all on Ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't know 2014 was 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Tor provides pre compiled, pre configured packages "Tor Browser"

https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

The TOR project believes they can maintain the "Tor Browser" faster than distributions and do so directly.

Either use the ppa  - https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser

or download the bundle directly , there are linux specific , distro independent instructions on the download page

> ## Linux Instructions
>
> Download the architecture-appropriate file above,
>   save it somewhere, then run one of the following two commands to
>   extract the package archive:
>
> ```
> tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-7.0.8_LANG.tar.xz
> ```
>
> or (for the 64-bit version):
>
> ```
> tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-7.0.8_LANG.tar.xz
> ```
>
> (where LANG is the language listed in the filename).
>
> Once that's done, switch to the Tor browser directory by running:
>
> ```
> cd tor-browser_LANG
> ```
>
> (where LANG is the language listed in the filename).
>
> To run Tor Browser, click either on the Tor Browser or the Tor Browser
>   Setup icon or execute the start-tor-browser.desktop file in a
>   terminal:
>
> ```
> ./start-tor-browser.desktop
> ```
>
> This will launch Tor Launcher and once that connects to Tor, it will
>   launch Firefox. **Do not unpack or run TBB as root**.