# How can I hide data usage from my ISP?

Tags: internet

I want to hide my internet use from my internet service provider, totally or partially. How may I do that?

Comment: @K7AAY 1. if you edit something in a review queue, it gets kicked out of the queue.  Use this power sparingly (E.G. if you're going to post an answer only) 2. will you post an answer here?  **0:-)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous Internet browsing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16086/anonymous-internet-browsing)

Answer (score 3):

This is nonsense. Data flows over IP packets, which have to be sent and received. If you're only interchanging packets with one site (your provider), there is NO WAY to keep that site from counting packets.

If you're going to use that much traffic (games, porn, business, or whatever), you'll have to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

Want to hide the *content* of your Internet traffic from your IP? Get a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network). It will not conceal that you are using a VPN, nor will it conceal how much traffic up and down you send and receive, and I know of no way to hide your volume (except to spread it between multiple ISPs).

A VPN encrypts all traffic before it leaves your PC and only the VPN server on the other end knows what's in it. [help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html.en](http://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html.en) and https://www.pcmag.com/article/352757/you-need-a-vpn-and-heres-why provide more information.

We can't pick one for you or advise which is best, so you have some studying to do. Websites which have VPN in their URL may have a vested interest in steering you one way or another.

Please, however, make sure that's not illegal where you are; it's against the law in some countries (e.g., the [Emirates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates)).