# Tor and Polipo installation steps

Tags: 12.04, tor, polipo

I am having a problem of installing and configuring Tor and Polipo on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to patch it in the system. I don't want to use the normal Vidalia program and browser. I need exactly to make it run in the system background and then i choose what to connect to it .. browsers or chat clients ..

Please i need set by step help and command line .. tor website doesnt show the exact help i needed

Answer (score 4):

So if I understand you correctly you don't want the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), but just Tor and Polipo running as daemon processes in the background. You can get a [Tor Ubuntu package](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) from the Tor Project. You have to do the following steps:

```
echo "deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org precise main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This appends the line beginning with `deb` in your `sources.list` (Please see also [How do I add a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/197564/236)). Furthermore you have to import the GnuPG key from the maintainer:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now you can install Tor and Polipo (from Ubuntu repository):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor polipo
```

Now you have to configure Polipo. A good choice is the [Polipo config file](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob_plain/1ffcd9dafb9dd76c3a29dd686e05a71a95599fb5:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf) from the Tor Project. It has all necessary settings. If you want to do it on your own. You need to edit `/etc/polipo/config`. The important settings are:

```
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
```

Now Polipo sends its requests through Tor. The last step ist to configure your applications. Please have a look at the [TorifyHOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO). There you'll find several applications and hints for torifying them.

Everytime when you start your computer Tor and Polipo will start in the background and wait for connections.

Comment: Just to clarify: polipo default http_port is 8123, so you have to set this in your browser or other application. For example in Mozilla Firefox you have to set Preferences>advanced>Network>connection Settings...>Manual proxy configuration:Http Proxy:127.0.0.1 Port:8123 and set Use this proxy server for all protocols Checked.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a fairly challenging task for a beginner, but just follow my instructions, and it should be fine.

First off, download the .tar.gz file, and SAVE it. Don't open it. Download Tor from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). (If you don't know whether your computer is 32-bit or 64-bit, then go to `System Settings`>`Details`>`Overview`>`OS Type`.)

If you've never used the Terminal before, then just remember this: press `Enter` between lines, but be SURE that you give it time to finish before you type the next thing. (You know it's ready for the next command if it looks like this: `user@user-computerModel-XY123:~$` . For example, mine looks like `james@james-OptiPlex-GX620:~$` .)
After you've downloaded your file, open the Terminal by pressing `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T`, and, (assuming that you saved it to `Downloads`,) type the following (for 32-bit):

```
cd Downloads
sudo cp tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz /opt/
```

NOTE: If you're using the 64-bit version, type this **instead**:

```
sudo cp tor-browser-gnu-linux-x86_64-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz /opt/
```

Now, change to the `/opt/` directory, extract the program, and remove the old file:

```
cd /opt/
sudo tar -xvf tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz
```

Again, for 64-bit, use the 64-bit filename INSTEAD OF THE OTHER ONE:

```
cd /opt/
sudo tar -xvf tor-browser-gnu-linux-x86_64-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz
sudo rm -rf tor-browser-gnu-linux-x86_64-2.2.39-1-dev-en-US.tar.gz
```

Okay, time to allow it to run:

```
sudo chmod 777 tor-browser_en-US/
```

Okay, it's now marked as executable, so it's time to create a symbolic link (this is what allows you to run it from the Terminal):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser /usr/bin/tor-browser
```

Okay, you're done. The program is now installed and runnable from the Terminal. (Type `tor-browser` to run it.)
What's this? You say you want to be able to run it from the launcher? No problem!
(NOTE: if you want an icon, find one online, and save it as `/opt/tor-browser_en-US/torbrowser.png`)

This part is fairly simple:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/tor-browser.desktop
```

Copy-and-paste this into the window:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Tor Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web Anonymously
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=tor-browser
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/tor-browser_en-US/torbrowser.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
```

Now, click "Save", close out the Terminal, and you're in business!

Sorry that tutorial took so long. Thanks for reading!

Comment: well first thank you for your kind reply .. i am not kind of beginner in this but the idea that i am having a problem with making the entire tor + polipo running in the background without need to make it visible i can stop it or run it from the terminal , the big deal now that i was doing it fast so i made the commands for 32 and then 64 , i need to clear the $opt and remove the previous installations and do this only for Ubuntu 12.4 Lts x64 sorry for causing a headache but its just one more try and we can do it .. can you be a little more patient with me .. thank you :)

Comment: in case its much easier for you to chat i can add my email : johnnysayigh@gmail.com , johnnysayigh@yahoo.com

Comment: Thanks. That comment was a bit confusing, but I think that a more chat-optimized environment will help me understand what's wrong.

Comment: how can be connected to you ! give a channel or a chat client

Comment: i did install Tor from the repository and i did connect initiated it and connected it to the browser with the new network configurations and its working .. but the problem now that when i install Polipo i am having the error polipo E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) , please i need an urgent help

Comment: Ooh. Crud. Sorry, but I don't know anything about Polipo. I know about Tor and Vidalia and the Tor Software Bundle, but I've only recently started looking at Polipo. I'll get back to you once I know some more about that. :(