# Connection timed out when connecting to a website (ubuntu only)

Tags: networking

I've been struggling with these problem for months. It happens randomly and it happens on Ubuntu only (12.04). It's about my hosted company website.

Some facts:

1. I can ping it
2. I can traceroute it
3. I can dig it
4. I can make a nslookup

But whenever I try to open it in Chrome it won't open. I also tried using polipo but got same connection time out issue.

I'm connected through a LAN network and I'm experiencing no problem with any other website.

Is there a more accurate debugging technique I'm missing other than pinging/tracerouting, etc.?

Comment: Temporarily solved it by using polipo + tor

Comment: can you put the steps as an answer so future visitors know how to solve it?

Comment: Here are several answers on Ask Ubuntu explaining it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/201185/tor-and-polipo-installation-steps

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `tcpdump` using something like this:

   ```
   tcpdump -nieth0 -s0 -w/tmp/dump.pcap port 80 or icmp
   ```

or if you are not logged in as **root**

```
    sudo tcpdump -nieth0 -s0 -w/tmp/dump.pcap port 80 or icmp
```

1. Attempt to access the website.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on `tcpdump` and then use the wireshark program to examine the capture file (`/tmp/dump.pcap`).  You can find Wireshark in the software centre.
3. Do the same for a website that does work, and look for relevant differences.
4. Do the same but at the hosting end.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate an MTU problem by pinging with increasingly large packets using ping's `-s` option, all the way up to 1492. If it turns out that large pings don't work, then something along your path cannot handle 1500-byte packets but is blocking the fragmentation needed packets from coming back.

Comment: Alternatively the `tracepath` command might help automating this process.