# Stopping TOR when the torsocks has been "source"d in bash

Tags: command-line, tor

How can I stop **Tor** ? 
I wanted to use **Tor** for every internet use in ubuntu but a command on internet makes this problem.

on start terminal I see this message :

```
Command '.torsocks' not found, did you mean:

command 'torsocks' from deb torsocks (2.3.0-2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Tor mode activated. Every command will be torified for this shell.

Torsocks MUST be sourced for this command to work
```

```
$ . torsocks on

Torsocks MUST be sourced for this command to work
```

```
$ . torsocks on

Tor mode activated. Every command will be torified for this shell.
```

I think this command makes this problem : `$ echo ". torsocks on" >> ~/.bashrc`

OS : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

`tor` can be stopped on Ubuntu by

```
sudo systemctl stop tor
```

Comment: !doesn't work !

Comment: It does work. But you are asking something unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **torify** a program you have to do either:

```
$ torsocks command
```

Or:

```
$ torify command
```

(the first one is preferred and the second one is kept for backward-compatibility).

But note that it's impossible to torify some programs like **Firefox** that way.For such programs you have to specify the proxy settings in the application itself.Or for **Chromium** you have to set the proxy system-wide via something like [Gnome Network](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/net-proxy.html.en)

By default you can use TOR only as a **SOCKS** proxy.In order to use it as an **HTTP(S)** proxy you can use for example [Polipo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201185/tor-and-polipo-installation-steps).

I use them regularly and there's no problem with torification.

Answer (score 0):

For a torified shell, meaning you receive this message in terminal:
Tor mode activated. Every command will be torified for this shell.

Turning it off is simply:
$ torify off

You will receive the message:
Tor mode deactivated. Command will NOT go through Tor anymore.

You can turn it off or on, as you like, using tor in one shell but not another.