# How to remove a particular PPA?

Tags: software-center, ppa

I have added Transmission PPA. After adding PPA, when I tried to open software updater I got the following messege.

Failed to load the package list

This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.

Even I could'nt open software sources, ubuntu software center, and sypnatic package manager.

What I have to do. Is there any command to remove the PPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command removes the `ppa`.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPANAME
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you but still I am getting the following message:E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_atareao_atareao_ubuntu_dists_quantal_main_i18n_Translation-en, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from Sagar Rakshe is correct. 
Here I explain how to perform it manually.

### Remove the repository

First, identify your wrong file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` 
(you may also have to check the main file `/etc/apt/sources.list`)

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
head *.list
```

Then, rename the file to disable it:

```
sudo mv  WRONGFILE.list  WRONGFILE.list.backup
```

Or instead of renaming the file, create a backup directory and move the file there:

```
sudo mkdir             backup_on_date_YYYMMDD
sudo mv WRONGFILE.list backup_on_date_YYYMMDD
```

For your information, `add-apt-repository` is a python script adding or commenting lines in your `*.list` files. Personally I prefer to handle myself these operations in order to keep clear & secure `*.list` files.

### Remove the package signing keys

Show the installed apt keys with `apt-key list` and find the key for the repo you want to remove, for example:

```
pub   2048R/5044912E 2010-02-11
uid                  Dropbox Automatic Signing Key <linux@dropbox.com>
```

You can then use `sudo apt-key del 5044912E` to remove this key.

Comment: this won't remove the repo signing keys. I'll edit your answer to include that info.

Comment: The `Remove the repository` and `Remove the package signing keys` sections should be used if an **upgrade** was accomplished too? For example from 20.04 to 22.04,  it with the purpose to let add the new keys for 22.04 and add the new repository - Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The graphical way of removing ppa repositories is as follows:

- open your **System Settings**
- click on the **Softare & Updates** icon
- go to the **Other Software** tab
- select the repository you want to remove
- click the **Remove** button

I hope this helps

Comment: Again, this won't remove the signing keys. You can remove them using the graphical interface too  -- under the Authetication tab in the Software Sources.