# repository does not have a release file

Tags: apt, ppa

I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I get the same error as the original error, also while exeucting it.

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/zeromq/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

What might it be?

Comment: The PPA provider simply doesn't provide packages beyond Wily (in effect, the PPA was abandoned 2 years ago). You will need to find an alternate repository for the software. What exactly do you need?

Comment: I need to get rid of the PPA (and preferably anything it has installed) so that `apt-get update` stops complaining.

Comment: You should be able to remove it using `apt-add-repository` or by manually editing your sources - see [How to remove a particular PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313907/how-to-remove-a-particular-ppa). Since the PPA doesn't provide packages for your release, it should not have installed anything.

Comment: "should not have installed anything" unless the system is an upgrade from earlier versions where it did.

Comment: install ppa manager gui and deal with it nicely for purging or removing https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager