# TOR unable to install keep recieving error msg

Tags: tar, tor

> tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2.1_en-US.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

I have followed the steps:

1. Make a backup copy of your current sources.list file

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
2. Append new line of text to current sources.list file

   ```
   CLI

   echo "new line of text" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

   GUI (Text Editor)

   sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
3. Paste new line of text on new line at end of current sources.list text file in Text Editor.

   Save and close sources.list

   Don't forget to update in order to use the new repository

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   (Found here [How do I add a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list))

so i come back to this step:

- Download the architecture-appropriate file above, save it somewhere, then run one of the following two commands to extract the package archive:

  ```
  tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2.1_en-US.tar.xz
  ```

  (Found here https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)

But i keep getting

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2.1_en-US.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: I have even tried sudo sudo tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-3.5.2.1_en-US.tar.xz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error message. **It can't find the file you're telling it to open.**

Assuming you've downloaded the file, you need to `cd` into the same directory in your terminal. So if you saved the file into `~/Downloads`:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32*
```

Comment: that's amazing, your amazing                                                           that worked!!!!                                                          Thank you so much