# Error loading share libraries: libgfortran.so.3 under Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: shared-library

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1.  Now, when I try to run a mpi Fortran code, there is an error loading the shared library: `libgfortran.so.3` and the code does not execute. I tried to reinstall `gfortran`, `mpich`, and `gcc` by removing the software, but I cannot remove them using `sudo apt-get remove gfortran` because the removal aborts when I am asked whether I want to continue. When I try to make an executable, an unknown file type is generated for the executable.

Comment: I believe you need to install libgfortran.  Sorry I don't know which version you'll require, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&keywords=libgfortran shows your options (*libgfortran-9-dev where 9 = version you need for mpi*)

Answer (score 14):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgfortran.so.3) you should install `libgfortran3` package, as it contains */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3*:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```

Note: if your software is 32-bit, then install two corresponding packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gfortran3 libx32gfortran3
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgfortran3 worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that some packages are not supported in Ubuntu 20.04, which is because of there dependency on previous versions of `gcc` or `libgfortran`.

In my case I was not able to install Seisan V11 on my Ubuntu 20.04.
Apparently this software should not be supporting in Ubuntu 20.04 because of error in shared libraries.

But some how I managed to solve the problem and now Seisan is working, although it has some back trace errors.

Make sure to go to this site and to do the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/65956351/16305143

One may use this site if they face any problem in editing `/etc/apt/sources.list.`
[How do I add a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list)