# How do I make an executable instead of a shared library under 18.04.1?

Tags: 18.04, executable

When I make a Fortran executable using `make` under 18.04.1, a shared library is made that is executable instead of an executable.   I have attached images comparing 18.04 and 18.04.1 results. How do I make an executable instead of a shared library?

[image: 18.04.1 results] [image: 18.04 results]

Comment: It hasn't made a shared library - it's made an executable that contains position independent code, which `libmagic` unfortunately misidentifies as a shared library - see this bug report [PIE executables (e.g. /usr/bin/ls) are detected as application/x-sharedlib](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97226) and/or this related question [Impossible to launch graphic executables in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871926/impossible-to-launch-graphic-executables-in-nautilus)

Comment: Is it possible to change this file type to executable?    It runs in a terminal window, but it currently cannot be distinguished from normal text files in a window.

Comment: I guess you could revert to an older version of gfortran (that doesn't create position independent executables by default). Otherwise, it may be possible to recompile using appropriate flags - for gcc/g++ you can use `-fno-pic` (compile) and `-no-pie` (link), not sure what the equivalents are for gfortran

Comment: When I upgraded to 18.04.1, I could not compile because a shared library was missing.  I assume that gfortran was updated during the upgrade to 18.04.1.  I installed the [shared library](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071288/533194) to fix the missing library.

Answer (score 0):

If it can help someone.
I had a similar problem. The program that I tried to compile was on an NTFS partition (shared btw windows and ubuntu). When I compile it on the NTFS partition, the output has a shared lib.
I moved all my project (source code and MakeFile) on my linux partition (ext4) and I compile it again. This time the output was an exectuable file.

Comment: Good to hear this worked for you, but without an explanation of how or why it worked, this is not really a complete answer.

Comment: I am not sure why it works, but the permission system is not the same between NTFS and EXT. Maybe another person with more knowledge can explain it.