# `libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` but the file is present

Tags: fortran

I want to evaluate the PARDISO (https://www.pardiso-project.org/) solver. I use MATLAB 2020b on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for testing it. When I download the corresponding files and want to run a test, I get the error `Invalid MEX-file '/home/<username>/Documents/PARDISO/ipopt.mexa64': libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` but the `.mexa64` file is present. I searched for this error and found out, that I most likely need gfortran3 to run this file but gfortran3 is not supported under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS anymore. What can I do? Is there any other possibility to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error loading share libraries: libgfortran.so.3 under Ubuntu 18.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071288/error-loading-share-libraries-libgfortran-so-3-under-ubuntu-18-04-1)

Comment: No, because like I wrote, Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support gfortran3 anymore. I get the error `E: Unable to locate package libgfortran3` if I want to install `libgfortran3`

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the exact problem that you're facing and I was able to overcome the problem by just copying a preexisting install of libfortran3. The link is "https://www.dropbox.com/s/01zxukpydgi749a/libgfort.tar?dl=1" choose either 32 or 64-bit option and extract it onto your `pardiso` install folder.

make sure you're adding the libfortran to your path with command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/your path here/pardiso_install_folder
```

Once that is done check if the .mexa64 executable has all the required libraries linked to it by doing a

```
ldd ipopt.mexa64
```

in the `pardiso` install folder and link the appropriate libraries. I am pretty new to all this too, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but can `pardiso` be used with GNU Octave?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi pardiso is compatible with MATLAB so it should be compatible with octave for the most part, but then again I cant say with 100% certainty. See if you can use MUMPS it has support for SCILAB which is open source AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct the problem with

1. First locate matlab's libgfortran file, for me it was in `<YOUR MATLAB PATH>/MATLAB/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0`
2. make a link of this file in same path `ln -s libgfortran.so.3.0.0 libgfortran.so.3`

The error disappeared afterwards for me.
Hope this helps someone.