# How to install Tor (Web Browser) in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: tor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)

I would like to install the Tor, but I'm having some problems. I know that **someone will say "This question is a exactly duplication of [How to install tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)", but it's not**, because the another question can not be applied to Ubuntu 12.10 as the deb command is not available anymore.

I did a research and even at the Tor's Official Website the available resource can not be applied to Ubuntu 12.10.

I tried to use the `deb` command (as the above question says: `deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main`) and the Terminal says `deb: command not found` and when I try to install it says `E: Unable to locate package deb`.

I've also tried to use the ppa: ubun-tor, but it's not compatible with Quantal Quetzal, because it's too old.

I've also tried to use `sudo apt-get install tor`, but browser icon don't shows up after installation and if you try to use the command tor in the Terminal I get the following error message:

```
Nov 26 10:59:25.731 [notice] Tor v0.2.3.22-rc (git-4a0c70a817797420) running on Linux.
Nov 26 10:59:25.731 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Nov 26 10:59:25.731 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Nov 26 10:59:25.737 [notice] Initialized libevent version 2.0.19-stable using method epoll (with changelist). Good.
Nov 26 10:59:25.737 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 26 10:59:25.737 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Nov 26 10:59:25.737 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Nov 26 10:59:25.737 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Thanks in advance.