# How do i install TOR browser on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)

I downloaded tor browser x86 from it's official website, it is a 30 MB .tar.gz file. how can i install it now?