# How to change IP address and IP location?

Tags: networking

I want to change my IP address and IP location manually or randomly for using the Internet anonymously, but I can't find the correct way to do this.

Please help me find any software to do above things.

Comment: You might consider VPN perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tor for this. 
This link will help you get it installed: [Installing Tor](https://askubuntu.com/a/306977/11932)
To know more about Tor, check out: http://torproject.org

This is how Tor is officialy described:

> Tor is free software and an open network that helps you defend against
>   a form of network surveillance that threatens personal freedom and
>   privacy, confidential business activities and relationships, and state
>   security known as traffic analysis

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be sign up for a vpn service like [private internet access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/). A VPN service like PIA will route your ip address through their servers and randomly assign an ip address to you from their available ips which will greatly increase your privacy while on the web.

However some of these services keep logs of the different ips that were assigned to you which could conflict with your privacy if these logs were accessed by external entities.

Keep this in mind if you end up looking for a vpn service. PIA states that they do not keep logs and it is only about $6 US per month for their service. They also have servers all over the united states, canada and europe so making a strong connection to one of their servers should be quite easy. Hope this wasn't too much of a plug for PIA. I have just been very pleased with their service and would recommend them for vpn use.