# How to send all traffics from wlan0 Access Point through a proxy (specifically Tor)?

Tags: wireless, proxy, tor, transparent-proxy

I created an access point from my wireless network card (`wlan0`) using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/417969/180452).

My Android device is connected to internet through this access point called `mylaptopAP`.

My laptop is connected to Internet through wired LAN network (`eth0`).

Now I want to redirect all traffics from/to my Android device (which is connected to `wlan0` AP) to Tor proxy. So that apps in my Android device could not find my location and identity from my Internet connection.

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/324685/180452) and [its answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/337992/180452), but it is about making transparent proxy for all of my laptop system, but I need this only be applied to my wireless traffics. Because Tor is slow and I do not like that my whole laptop browsing/downloads become slow. I just need only traffics related to `wlan0` access point are redirected to Tor.

Comment: I think your assumption that "I do not need this" is wrong. You do need a local proxy set up, the next step is making sure that everything from wlan0 is passed through that proxy. I don't know the answer but you could probably read up on iptables and learn how to make the rules mentioned unique for a special device only.

Comment: @pzkpfw Thank you, I edited the question so it better represents my need.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script for exactly what you need
https://github.com/garywill/linux-router

`# lnxrouter --ap wlan0 SSID --password PASSWORD --tp 9040 --dns-proxy 9053`

In `torrc`

`TransPort 0.0.0.0:9040 
DNSPort 0.0.0.0:9053`