# VPN in non-browser applications?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, steam

I am at a boarding university with restricted internet access (most broad-band using sites (YT, other video sites, gaming content sites) are blocked). I can bypass the YT blockade easily in browsers using a VPN.

Is this also possible for the general internet access? 
For example, I cannot use/update skype, Steam or any other application using the Internet, because these applications cannot access the Internet.

In the network settings there is an option for proxy networks and then I could apply systemwide after entering the IPs and port ID. Is it as simple as that and I just need specific data (IP, port # etc.)? If yes, is there a source that gives these access data for free?

best, 
Mo

Answer (score 1):

Most common usage of VPN is to tunnel entire internet connection on system on which it's set. I've no idea how you did it only for browser... Did you perhaps meant Tor Browser? It's a different network. There are some free VPN's, but for good one you will need to pay.

You can redirect entire connection with free Tor network, check "[TORtp](https://github.com/vinc3nt/stem-TORtp)". Don't know how and if it will work on Ubuntu, seen it on "Freepto" OS and there's also similar solution on "Tails" OS. I've found however this topic for Ubuntu:

[How to route all internet traffic through Tor (the onion router)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324685/how-to-route-all-internet-traffic-through-tor-the-onion-router)

Comment: That's not entirely true. VPN can either be used to route all traffic through it or to bridge two systems. The latter is useful if network services from the university should remain usable.

Comment: Good point. Fixed my answer to be more clear of what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to route ALL traffic through a VPN. It will depend on the setup of both machines.

You will almost certainly need to pay for a good VPN, there are free options, but they usually have some catch, limited speed, strange software, time limits. Try this link http://www.thetop10bestvpn.com/best-free-vpn-service

Also be aware that some web sites will load pages inside their page to try an bypass filters. This is not a "real" VPN.