# Bypass Authenticated HTTP Proxy :Ubuntu

Tags: networking, proxy, authentication, privoxy

Is there any way to bypass authenticated http proxy to something like 127.0.0.1:port, so that we could use it any application, simply by filling out the proxy 127.0.0.1:port (which could be used for applications that don't have options of filling proxy_username and proxy_passsword).

I have tried privoxy, but I could make it work only with tor proxy. I am unable to figure out where to fill the proxy and authentication details of my http proxy in the config file.

Please say if privoxy could help, or if there's some other alternative

P.S. :  I know that tor could be a suggestion, but I don't want to browse anonymously. I just want to bypass my authenticated proxy to unauthenticated one.

Comment: Did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor ?

Comment: @Jobin i have already installed tor on my machine

Answer (score 1):

To start tor browser from terminal, to the path where you have downloaded and extracted tor(assuming it is in ~/) and then:

```
cd tor-browser_en-US
```

and to start tor:

```
./start-tor-browser
```

When this window pops up:

[image: tor starting]

Click on **Settings -> Network** and add your Address, Port, Username and Password and if your ISP blocks connecting to tor network, you may need to add bridges to make it work. To add a bridge, please [refer to this turorial](http://anonygreen.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/how-to-setup-a-tor-relay-or-tor-bridge/).

Comment: i did not ask how to install and use tor. Tor allows browsing over anonymous IPs, and I don't want to hide IP at all. All I want is just to bypass the proxy, and not to make my browing anonymous.

Comment: Extremely sorry but I am not aware of any method that would serve the purpose without this.