# GPG error while trying to install tor from external repository

Tags: tor, keyserver, gpg

Hello All I am Having a problem in installing tor in ubuntu....when i start adding tor repository to my system and write the command

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
```

then a error comes which is

```
gpg: Invalid option "--keyserver.ubuntu.com"
hailendra@hailendra-Ideapad-Z570:~$ gpg --keyserver keys.ubuntu.com --recv 886DDD89
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 886DDD89 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

can any one help me what to do?

Comment: Which guid did you follow? Which repository did you add? Is it a Ubuntu PPA, why did you not use `add-apt-repository` then? Have you tried installing the tor package that is already in the Ubuntu repository? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor) Most of the answers are obsolete, but one of the answers is up-to-date.

Comment: Tor has nothing to do with gpg. You can install Tor even with no gpg in your system. So are you looking for guidance on Tor installation? please edit your question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to install from a secured repository you will need to add their public key to apt.

You should have received an information on where to get the public key from the makers of the repository. Download this key and save it on your drive.

The we can add this key with

```
sudo apt-key add </path/name_of_downloaded_key_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyserver keys.ubuntu.com seems not to be active at the moment. You can however use keys.gnupg.net:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score -1):

try `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 886DDD89` this should work

try directly copy and execute command from line above, in your question you have mistake in input string `gpg: Invalid option "--keyserver.ubuntu.com"`

and you should use keyserver.ubuntu.com instead of keys.ubuntu.com

when key is received export it using this: `gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -

If this doesn't work please post output of this command: `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.net  --search-keys 886DDD89`

Comment: Already tried running that command in the question, but it resulted in the error: `gpgkeys: key 886DDD89 not found on keyserver`