# tor browser install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, tor

I have read the answers to other questions regarding the install/running of the tor browser. I have tried the answers given but still cannot get the tor browser to run on mine. I have Ubuntu 14.04 and where it shows to start tor browser when I double click all I get is an open tab full of code. Anyone with suggestions I should try? I also tried downloading from tor project did not work and tried the install using command in the terminal and it also did not work. When I had windows, I had no problem with the install or the tor browser running. I really like Ubuntu better; this is the only thing that I am having trouble with. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: there should be a firefox version with the install folder... try that...

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: @hiyaimlisa, I have updated the canonical answer to installing Tor Browser Bundle here to note that "start-tor-browser" must be executable. If it is not executable, you can only display (and edit) the code. Hope that helps! https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu/420261

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Install from Terminal:

**Note:** If you installed older version of Tor-Browser, in first you must clear the old `.tor-browser-en` folder from home folder. Just clear that by using: `cd ~ && rm -r .tor-browser-en`

Then type following line one by one in Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) to install Tor-Browser.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Now open dash and type "Tor", click on and use.

Comment: I'm sure webupd8team updates their packages very consistently and quickly, however I would note that if you install Tor Browser Bundle the way @purbleguy suggests instead, the browser will update itself very soon after an update is available. For someone needing to retain their anonymity, this could be critical. This also removes the need to trust that webupd8team has not made any bad changes to the software (not that they would, but removing trust is always a good idea in this field).

Answer (score 22):

Alright, I'll lead you step by step on how to run the Tor browser

---

1. Download the latest tor tarball from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#linux)
2. open a terminal window and navigate to the directory you downloaded it to
3. run this command: `tar -xvf <NAME_OF_TARBALL>`
4. use `cd` to go into the created directory
5. use this command to give the start script permission to run: `chmod +x start_tor_browser.sh`
6. run the start script with `./start_tor_browser.sh`

---

That should work, let me know if it doesn't and I'll look into it more

Comment: I tried the commands. the first command said syntax error near unexpected token 'newline' the start command said no such file or directory

Comment: Alright, I'm going to be specific and say it's in the Downloads directory, what you would do is `cd ~/Downloads` then do tar -xvf tor-browser-linux64-3.6.4_en-US.tar.xz (Thats if you have the 64 bit tar file) use this command: `cd tor-browser-linux64-3.6.4_en-US` then follow commands 5 and 6, if that doesn't work. then I don't understand the problem and can't help you @hiyaimlisa

Comment: please change #5 to `chmod +x start-tor-browser.desktop` and #6 to "double click start tor browser" icon in the dir.