# How do i install TOR on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I have the tar.xz file in my downloads folder for TOR BROWSER. 
But i have no idea on how to install it 
Please help

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/a/420261/13247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you downloaded the file should have also had instructions.  https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux

A tar.xz file is a tarball. You can extract it using the tar command, then change working directory to the new directory and run the start-tor-browser script

```
$ tar xf tor-browser-linux64-4.0_en-US.tar.xz
$ cd tor-browser_en-US/
$ ./start-tor-browser
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question has been asked very many times](https://askubuntu.com/a/420261/13247).

The Browser Bundle isn't 'installed'.  It's a script you'll run when you want to utilize Tor.

Answer (score 0):

Simply on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

And then you can use either directly use the tor browser or proxy switchy extension to use tor in chrome.