# Are all OpenPGP public key server equal?

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, keyserver

An error info occur when to execute `apt-get update` .

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.

```
GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org jessie InRelease: The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
```

I found an answer:

```
gpg --keyserver  key_server_name  --recv-keys  A2F683C52980AECF
gpg --armor --export A2F683C52980AECF| apt-key add -
```

There are two `pool.sks-keyservers.net` and `keys.gnupg.net` among many public key servers, are they equal?

```
gpg --keyserver  pool.sks-keyservers.net  --recv-keys  A2F683C52980AECF
gpg --keyserver  keys.gnupg.net  --recv-keys  A2F683C52980AECF
```

Do the two commands take same effect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most OpenPGP key servers are integrated in the [SKS key server pool](https://sks-keyservers.net/) and exchange keys among each other. You can have a look at the [pool status pages](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/) to get an overview of the contained servers. `pool.sks-keysevers.net` resolves to a (weighted) random choice of those servers.

Actually, `keys.gnupg.net` is a simple alias for `pool.sks-keyservers.net` (technically speaking, a `CNAME` to this domain):

```
$ host keys.gnupg.net
keys.gnupg.net is an alias for pool.sks-keyservers.net.
[...]
```

In the end, it does not matter which server you choose, as long as it is contained in the pool. Using `pool.sks-keyservers.net` is a safe choice, and `keys.gnupg.net` is equivalent.

A typical answer of a key server that is *not* synchronizing is the [PGP Global Directory](https://keyserver2.pgp.com/vkd/GetWelcomeScreen.event), which also performs a simple ownership verification of the mail addresses contained.

Answer (score 2):

Key servers exchange keys. That is why it does not matter which server to use.

Answer (score 2):

There's now also `keys.openpgp.org` which deliberately is NOT part of the SKS server pool:

> **Is this server part of the "SKS" pool?**
>
> No. The federation model of the SKS pool has various problems in terms of reliability, abuse-resistance, privacy, and usability. We might do something similar to it, but keys.openpgp.org will never be part of the SKS pool itself.

See also [this blog post](https://gist.github.com/rjhansen/67ab921ffb4084c865b3618d6955275f) for more background.