# TOR browser doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, tor, tor-browser

I downloaded the tor browser from Ubuntu Software Center but it doesn't work, and shows this message:

[image]

but when I downloaded it from the tor website then it worked.

Comment: Have you tried to delete it and download it again with a stable connection. It's probably only the SHA 1 that doesn't match.

Comment: I delete and install, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you checked sha1 manually ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu) Read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu/895999#895999

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it's supposed to be. You only download the Tor Browser from their official website (torproject.org).

From its looks it seems that you're using Micah Lee's Tor Browser Launcher, which you also shouldn't download from the Software Center, rather use,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

In any case, to solve your problem use this command:

```
gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu
```

That should fix your problem.