# Which Tor to install on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS?

Tags: tor

I do not understand what option to install on this instruction https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu "Tor" or "Tor from source" , what's the difference?

Comment: Those instructions are not the easiest instructions to follow for Ubuntu 16.04 and later. The latest instructions for quickly and easily installing the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu 16.04 and later are in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu/895999#895999

Answer (score 0):

'tor' gives you the binary only.  (the code your machine runs)

'tor from source' gives your the source code us humans read. this allows you to inspect it, [potentially change] then compile it yourself to get the binary that way. 'from source' is an option you only see with open source software.

Answer (score -1):

Tor from source : you download the source code build the app and install it

Tor : you download the builded app and install it -> The most easy