# How do I restore /usr/bin/env after overwriting it with start-tor-browser file

Tags: apt, software-installation

I was installing Tor and wanted to access it directly from the terminal, so I was trying to copy `start-tor-browser` to `/usr/bin`. But by mistake, I have replaced the `/usr/bin/env` file with the `start-tor-browser` file. What should I do now??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` is provided by the [`coreutils`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coreutils) package. [karel's way using a single command](https://askubuntu.com/a/976033/22949) will likely work, but I suggest replacing `/usr/bin/env` with a symbolic link to `/bin/busybox` first, in case a removal or installation script attempts to use `env` (which is generally assumed to be present).

First move the wrong file you put there aside, or delete it if you know you don't need that file. This renames it from `env` to `env.old`:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/env{,.old}
```

Then make `/usr/bin/env` a symbolic link to `/bin/busybox`. When run with the name `env`, [`busybox`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/busybox.1.html) will behave as the [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/env.1.html) command:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/busybox /usr/bin/env
```

Then perform the reinstallation. The symbolic link you have just created will be used if necessary, will have no ill effect if it wasn't needed, and will be replaced automatically with the proper `env` executable installed from the `coreutils` package:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install coreutils
```

In general, [if you need to know what package provides a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file), you can run `dpkg -S /path/to/file` (in this case, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/env`), which works so long as the package is installed even if the file itself has been damaged or deleted. Or you can use the *Search the contents of packages* section of [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), which does not require that you use the full path; you would just select your Ubuntu release and type in `env`.

Answer (score 4):

The env file at `/usr/bin/env` is provided by the coreutils package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

It is also apparent from your question that you did not install the Tor Browser bundle the easy way with apt as it is possible to do in Ubuntu 16.04 and later. To install the Tor Browser bundle in Ubuntu 16.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
```

torbrowser-launcher handles downloading the most recent version of Tor Browser Bundle for you, in your language and for your architecture. After installing Tor Browser, it can be launched by searching for tor in the Dash and clicking the Tor Browser icon. The Tor Browser Launcher Settings app is also installed along with Tor Browser.

[image: IMG:]

To start Tor Browser from the terminal run this command:

```
torbrowser-launcher
```

Sometimes torbrowser-launcher does not work after installing it. torbrowser-launcher failed to install Tor Browser when I tested it  in both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04. If this happens please refer to the alternate instructions for installing Tor Browser in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/895999/) which worked successfully in Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

Comment: +1 nice one, just was searching for which package provides it.

Comment: will apt-get install work without /usr/bin/env?

Comment: Yes, I tested it without env by temporarily renaming my env to env.bak and it worked perfectly even without env.

Comment: +1 Though I don't know if it will work on every Ubuntu release, so I prefer to make an `env` symlink to `busybox` first, just reinstalling `coreutils` as shown here *is* reasonable: if it *does* fail, it is still possible to make the symlink and tell `apt` to fix the half-completed transaction. Also, the `torbrowser-launcher` part is actually related to the core issue of replacing files in `/usr/bin` and is a valuable addition. Actions like overwriting `/usr/bin/env` *usually* happen when one attempts to install something with in a hard manual way that's better done in an easy automatic way.