# How do I install Tor Onion Browser on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, tor

I followed the [tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/895999/) and got a

> SIGNATURE VERIFICATION FAILED!

error when trying to launch the program. So I re-inputted this in command line:

```
gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu
```

(I highlighted it differently this time and the terminal result came out more successfully[?]) then relaunched Tor, now it's stuck at 0% on

> Downloading and installing Tor Browser for the first time.

I'm now trying to launch Tor but when I click the program nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tor-browser-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux . It is about installing Tor browser in Ubuntu 18.04.

> #### Download Tor Browser
>
> The first step is to head over to the [official Tor
>   Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)
>   website and download the latest Linux Tor Browser package and the relevant
>   *.asc signature.
>
> Please be aware that the Tor project is often a target for hackers and
>   DDOS attacks. For this reason we are now going to check for correct
>   signing signatures of our downloaded Tor Browser package.
>
> Assuming that you have downloaded the tor browser package and
>   signatures to your `/~Downloads` directory first import "Tor Browser
>   Developers" signing key. Execute the below command:
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys D1483FA6C3C07136
> gpg: key 4E2C6E8793298290: public key "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) " imported
> gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
> gpg: Total number processed: 1
> gpg:               imported: 1
> ```
>
> Navigate to the Downloads directory and confirm that both Tor Browser
>   package and its signature are present:
>
> ```
> ls
> tor-browser-linux64-7.5_en-US.tar.xz  tor-browser-linux64-7.5_en-US.tar.xz.asc
> ```
>
> Next verify the signature of the Tor Browser package:
>
> ```
> gpg --verify tor-browser-linux64-7.5_en-US.tar.xz.asc tor-browser-linux64-7.5_en-US.tar.xz
> gpg: Signature made Tue 23 Jan 2018 11:50:13 AEDT
> gpg:                using RSA key D1483FA6C3C07136
> gpg: Good signature from "Tor Browser Developers (signing key) " [unknown]
> gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
> gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
> Primary key fingerprint: EF6E 286D DA85 EA2A 4BA7  DE68 4E2C 6E87 9329 8290
>      Subkey fingerprint: A430 0A6B C93C 0877 A445  1486 D148 3FA6 C3C0 7136
> ```
>
> [image] 
>   <sup>**Tor Browser signature verification**</sup>
>
> Check for a good signature from "Tor Browser Developers" text on line 4 of the 
>   above screenshot. All seems to be in order!
>
> #### Extract Tor Browser
>
> Still in the Downloads directory, extract the Tor Browser package into
>   a root of your home directory:newly
>
> ```
> tar xJpf tor-browser-linux64-7.5_en-US.tar.xz -C ~/
> ```
>
> #### Start Tor Browser
>
> To start the Tor Browser on your Ubuntu, change directories to your home
>   directory and navigate to the newly extracted tor-browser directory
>   using the `cd` command:
>
> ```
> cd  
> cd tor-browser_en-US/
> ```
>
> From here start Tor Browser:
>
> ```
> ./start-tor-browser.desktop
> ```
>
> Alternatively register Tor Browser as a local application, thus
>   create an icon shortcut accessible via the Applications launcher:
>
> ```
> ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
> ```
>
> [image]
>   <sup>**Start Tor Browser on Ubuntu 18.04**</sup>
>
> [image]
>   <sup>**Wait for the Tor Browser to connect to a Tor network.**</sup>
>
> [image]
>   <sup>**Click Test Tor Network Settings link to perform Tor Browser test.**</sup>
>
> [image]
>   <sup>**If the IP address you see is not your private external IP address then you are good to go to browse privately!**</sup>

Comment: How do I download the relevant *.asc signature? When I click on (sig) it shows me this a wall consisting of completely random text/symbols/numbers starting with "-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----" then ending with "-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----"

Comment: @userr That's what the .asc signature (tor-browser-linux64-8.0.2_en-US.tar.xz) is supposed to look like for Tor Browser 8.0 (tor-browser-linux64-8.0.2_en-US.tar.xz). See this link: https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-8.0.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc

Comment: Yes that, do I enter it into the terminal or do I paste it into a Wordpad file? Or do I just right-click then "Save linked content as"? I'm very new to Linux.

Comment: When using external links, nowadays we would use: [3 ways Install Tor Browser on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-tor-browser-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/)