# Problem setting shortcut for Tor Browser

Tags: shortcut-keys, tor

I've installed Tor Browser and I can run it buy the command:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

This command works as long as the *Tor icon*(the globe icon) is in : **/home/user/tor-browser_de/** and I am also there in  ~/tor-browser_de.

When I want to set the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I use the command `./start-tor-browser.desktop`, but it does not work. I copied the *Tor icon* to **/home/user**, but the problem still persists. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Provide the full path to the file, i.e. `/home/user/tor-browser_de/start-tor-browser.desktop`. I'm not sure if running a `.desktop` file works in the context of a shortcut though. If not, open the file in a text editor and use the command specified in the `Exec=...` line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu) Read the answer titled *Ubuntu 16.04 and later*.

Answer (score 1):

The command needs the full path. I've tried it with a bash-script for now and `./Path/To/File/Script.sh` does not work. But `bash /Path/To/File/Script.sh` does.

In: [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) i found it should be `deskopen`, so the command for your shortcut should be:

```
deskopen /home/user/tor-browser_de/start-tor-browser.desktop
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: +1, but unfortunately the command does not work(it gives the error *command not found*), I am trying to solve it by the link that you've attached.

Comment: @Coditoergosum unrelated to this post: please don't suggest edits where the only change is gparted->GParted.

Comment: @ guntbert  thanks for comment, I'll try to improve my edits. But I don't understand whats wrong with correcting **GParted**? You have rejected one of my posts in which I had corrected **GParted** 5 times. I see edits in which only one letter is capitalizad.

Comment: @Coditoergosum opinions about what is a valuable edit differ of course. In my opinion case alone isn't worth the effort. I got the feeling that you were starting to search for all occurrences of gparted...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) attached by @Patient32Bit . There is an answer that says:

> The answer should be
>
> `xdg-open program_name.desktop`
>
> But due to a bug this no longer works.

But the answer goes to 2010, and it seems that the bug is fixed. I set the shortcut by:

```
xdg-open start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Most correct way is to edit .desktop file. Open it with text editor, and change path to tor to correct one. Then everything should work fine, including keyboard shortcut.

As I remember in tor bundle is relative path, so you can unpack it and run. Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

command you can create a shortcut to applications and you can run tor in applications