# lubuntu - How to install the latest Tor Browser. 18.04 version

Tags: lubuntu

I've been trying to install the Tor browser in my laptop and I can't seem to install it. I've tried searching for answers in threads that already existed but I can't seem to find that works for me.

Comment: Does this resoource help? https://webtips4u.com/guides/linux/how-to-install-tor-browser-for-ubuntu-18-04-ubuntu-16-04-os/ and is there an issue between 32bit and 64bit?

Comment: I face the same problem  wen I install the Tor Browser using other guides. I was able to install it but I can't seem to run it. It'll run, say it's installing Tor browser, then have an error.

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher` which will "*helps download and run the Tor Browser Bundle*" for you automatically. (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=torbrowser-launcher)  Nothing more needs to be done in my experience, it actually downloads the latest version on run (the package itself doesn't contain the browser, just causes it to be downloaded & installed when first run).  Your issue may be network related, ie. connecting to tor to download it is blocked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing the `apt-transport-https package` that is necessary to access a repository over HTTPS and enabling the Universe repository:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Import the Tor Apt repository GPG key to your system using the following wget command:

```
wget -q -O - https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

The command above should output OK, which means that the key has been successfully imported and packages from this repository will be considered trusted.

Enable the Tor repository:

```
echo "deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once the repository is enabled, update the apt package list and install the latest version of the Tor Browser by typing:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring torbrowser-launcher
```

That’s it. Tor Browser has been installed on your Linux desktop

Answer (score 0):

The other answer doesn't function ant more.
When I type "torbrowser-launcher" a window opens saying error 404.
If I type simply "torbrowser", it says "command not found"

Go to this link :
https://www.torproject.org/download/

Choose your operating system, then the download starts. After you extract the files from the tar, you go one step in the directory and you double-click setup.

After, the setup file disappears and is replaced by start-tor-browser.desktop

You can launch it in a terminal :
cd to the directory and type
./start-tor-browser.desktop

Doesn't function for 32 bits architectures. If you have an old machine - thank you for caring for the planet - follow the instructions here:
https://tb-manual.torproject.org/downloading/

If you choose to send an email to gettor@torproject.org
write linux32 as title and body to get links for 32 bits architectures. Then you follow the procedure described above.

The setup file didn't disappear when I double-clicked it, but viewing the folder contents in a terminal I saw the start-tor-browser.desktop file. After a while it also appeared in the tor folder and I was able to drag it to the desktop.

Comment: Tor Browser doesn't *support* 32bit anymore, because of firefox and changing libraries.   18.04 is also reaching End of Standard Support this year which is a concern.

Comment: As for the torbrowser-launcher failure, that's a Known Bug that I'm working on figuring out 'best approach' to fix in older releases by SRU - refer to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077 about the 404 error problem.  (Debian is also unfixed as well, but Upstream is fixed)