# Having Qt issues when installing Tor

Tags: 20.04, qt, tor

Trying to install tor browser using `sudo apt install -y torbrowser-launcher`. Everything installs fine with no errors, then I run `torbrowser-launcher` and get this.

```
$ torbrowser-launcher
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.3.2
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried googling for some fixes/ways to fix this but nothing so far has fixed my issue and my Linux knowledge is not good enough to do this on my own.

edit: I am running Ubuntu on my laptop as its only operating system, no VM's or anything.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Tor Browser package directly from their website? It should run without any installation necessary, just need to unpack it.

Comment: Yes but I get a .desktop file which I cannot run, only open in a text editor

Comment: You should be able to run the start-tor-browser.desktop file from a terminal, or via right-click, or by actually putting it in your ~/Desktop directory and double-clicking it on the desktop. But maybe you will have to adapt the path to the executable to where you actually unpacked it.

Comment: It's not letting me run, it just opens a text editor.

Comment: Managed to fix it somehow it just popped up as a program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the method which you've used, I would suggest that  you install Tor Browser as follows.

1. Navigate to the Tor Browser [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download).
2. Download the GNU/Linux .tar.xz file
3. (Recommended) Verify the file's signature. The steps for verifying the file's signature are shown below.
4. When the download is complete, extract the archive with the command `tar -xf [TB archive]` or with the Archive Manager.
5. Navigate to the newly extracted Tor Browser directory. Right-click on *start-tor-browser*, open *Properties* and change the permission to *Allow executing file as program* by clicking the checkbox.
6. Start Tor Browser from the command line by running:

   ```
    ./start-tor-browser
   ```

Comment: I updated the steps because the old instructions don't work anymore in 22.04. Now they are up to date for 20.04 and 22.04.