# How to tell Tor Browser where to save downloaded files

Tags: 20.04, downloads, tor-browser

I managed to get Tor and Tor Browser installed in Ubuntu 20.04 and downloaded some files (so I thought), but the downloaded files were nowhere to be found when I searched for them in Files in my Downloads folder.

I went into the Tor settings and saw that files would be downloaded to a Downloads folder. By clicking on the Download icon a window popped up showing all my downloaded files. They seemed to stored under the Tor Browser in a Downloads folder. All the downloaded files could be seen there (somewhat dimmed), but they could be opened or moved.

The files were however nowhere to be found in my normal Downloads folder. How do I get access to the files downloaded by the Tor browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tor Browser](https://askubuntu.com/q/382394/) bundle is bundled with a modified version of Firefox. Select the Firefox *Settings* menu (3 horizontal lines **≡** icon in the upper right corner) and under the *Files and Applications* section in the *Downloads* settings click the *Browse* button and select your default Ubuntu Downloads directory where it says *Save files to* or put a check in the checkbox next to *Always ask you where to save files*.

[image]

Comment: The Firefox Settings menu is the same in the Tor Settings browser environment.

Comment: Thank you Karel,
problem solved.

I just dont know to remove my question from ????
but it is solved

Comment: All of the websites on the Stack Exchange network have the same rule that no user can delete their own question if it has an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two slightly different questions, @Karel answered the first of these.

In answer to "How do I get access to the files downloaded by the Tor browser?", for me they are in:

`~/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/`