# I'm having trouble installing TOR browser bundle on Ubuntu 22.04, Please help?

Tags: 22.04, tor

Edit: I just want to say that when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 I checked the box that said "look for and install 3rd party software", usually I don't check that box but this time I chose to. Just thought I'd throw that out there.

This is a clean install of 22.04 just so you know. I previously did an upgrade and ran into bugs.

This article has 3 ways to install TOR on Ubuntu 22.04 and I tried all three of them to no avail. https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-tor-browser-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/ I tried the "#1st method using manual Tarball file" I will show you what I typed in the terminal

```
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Downloads
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ tar -xvf tor-browser-linux64-12.0_ALL.tar.xz
tor-browser/
tor-browser/Browser/
tor-browser/Browser/.config/
tor-browser/Browser/.config/gtk-3.0/
tor-browser/Browser/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/Caches/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/extensions/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/extensions/{73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232}.xpi
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profiles.ini
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/geoip6
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc-defaults
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/fontconfig/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/fontconfig/fonts.conf
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/ChangeLog.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Firefox.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/HTTPS-Everywhere.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Libevent.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/NoScript.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Noto-CJK-Font.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Noto-Fonts.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/PluggableTransports/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/PluggableTransports/LICENSE
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/PluggableTransports/LICENSE.CC0
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/PluggableTransports/LICENSE.GO
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/PluggableTransports/LICENSE.SNOWFLAKE
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Tor-Launcher.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Tor.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Licenses/Torbutton.txt
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/snowflake/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/snowflake/README.md
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/snowflake-client
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libcrypto.so.1.1
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libevent-2.1.so.7
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libssl.so.1.1
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libstdc++/
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/tor
tor-browser/Browser/abicheck
tor-browser/Browser/application.ini
tor-browser/Browser/browser/
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default32.png
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
tor-browser/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default64.png
tor-browser/Browser/browser/features/
tor-browser/Browser/browser/features/onboarding@mozilla.org.xpi
tor-browser/Browser/browser/omni.ja
tor-browser/Browser/defaults/
tor-browser/Browser/defaults/pref/
tor-browser/Browser/defaults/pref/channel-prefs.js
tor-browser/Browser/dependentlibs.list
tor-browser/Browser/execdesktop
tor-browser/Browser/firefox
tor-browser/Browser/firefox.real
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Arimo-Bold.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Arimo-BoldItalic.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Arimo-Italic.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Cousine-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansAdlam-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansArmenian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBalinese-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBamum-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBassaVah-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansChakma-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansDeseret-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansElbasan-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansGeorgian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansGrantha-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansGunjalaGondi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansHanifiRohingya-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansHebrew-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansJavanese-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKR-Regular.otf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKhmer-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKhojki-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansKhudawadi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansLao-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansLisu-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMahajani-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMalayalam-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMandaic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMasaramGondi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMedefaidrin-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMendeKikakui-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMiao-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansModi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMongolian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMro-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMultani-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansNKo-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansNewTaiLue-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansNewa-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansOriya-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansOsage-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansOsmanya-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansPahawhHmong-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansPauCinHau-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansRunic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSamaritan-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSharada-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansShavian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSoraSompeng-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSoyombo-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansSyriac-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTC-Regular.otf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTagalog-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTakri-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTamil-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTelugu-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansThai-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAPT-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAdrar-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAgrawImazighen-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAhaggar-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAir-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghAzawagh-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghGhat-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghHawad-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghRhissaIxa-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghSIL-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTifinaghTawellemmet-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansTirhuta-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansVai-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansWancho-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansWarangCiti-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSansZanabazarSquare-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifArmenian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifBalinese-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifBengali-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifDevanagari-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifDogra-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifEthiopic-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifGeorgian-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifGrantha-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifGujarati-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifGurmukhi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifHebrew-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifKannada-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifKhmer-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifKhojki-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifLao-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifMalayalam-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifMyanmar-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifNyiakengPuachueHmong-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifSinhala-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifTamil-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifTelugu-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifThai-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifTibetan-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/NotoSerifYezidi-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/STIXMath-Regular.otf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Tinos-Bold.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Tinos-BoldItalic.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Tinos-Italic.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/Tinos-Regular.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/fonts/TwemojiMozilla.ttf
tor-browser/Browser/icons/
tor-browser/Browser/icons/updater.png
tor-browser/Browser/libfreeblpriv3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libipcclientcerts.so
tor-browser/Browser/liblgpllibs.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozavcodec.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozavutil.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozgtk.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozsandbox.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozsqlite3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libmozwayland.so
tor-browser/Browser/libnspr4.so
tor-browser/Browser/libnss3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libnssckbi.so
tor-browser/Browser/libnssutil3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libplc4.so
tor-browser/Browser/libplds4.so
tor-browser/Browser/libsmime3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libsoftokn3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libssl3.so
tor-browser/Browser/libxul.so
tor-browser/Browser/omni.ja
tor-browser/Browser/platform.ini
tor-browser/Browser/plugin-container
tor-browser/Browser/precomplete
tor-browser/Browser/removed-files
tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser
tor-browser/Browser/start-tor-browser.desktop
tor-browser/Browser/tbb_version.json
tor-browser/Browser/update-settings.ini
tor-browser/Browser/updater
tor-browser/Browser/updater.ini
tor-browser/start-tor-browser.desktop
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ cd tor-browser_ALL/
bash: cd: tor-browser_ALL/: No such file or directory
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ cd tor-browser_en-US/
bash: cd: tor-browser_en-US/: No such file or directory
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
bash: ./start-tor-browser.desktop: No such file or directory
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$
```

So if you look at the article and follow the steps you'll see I got to "Switch to extract the folder" and that's where I ran into trouble.

Now, the other two steps do work and will successfully install TOR browser bundle on my computer but when I launch TOR it says "Download error: 404" I even took a screenshot for you. I should add that I even installed TOR from the Ubuntu Software store and it said the same thing when I launched TOR, Download error: 404. So yeah I'm totally stumped.

[image: TOR download error: 404]

Edit: This is for Alejandro, I did what you told me to do and this is the result. I don't think it worked.

```
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for computer: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
python3-distupgrade/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.15 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.13]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.15 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.13]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:22.04.15 all [upgradable from: 1:22.04.13]
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ apt install tor
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
tor is already the newest version (0.4.6.10-1).
tor set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Edit:

```
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt autoremove --purge tor
[sudo] password for computer: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tor* tor-geoipdb* torsocks*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 15.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 197075 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tor-geoipdb (0.4.6.10-1) ...
Removing tor (0.4.6.10-1) ...
Removing torsocks (2.3.0-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
(Reading database ... 197020 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for tor (0.4.6.10-1) ...
Purging configuration files for torsocks (2.3.0-3) ...
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  snap  Templates  Videos
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ cd Downloads/
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ ls
tor-browser  tor-browser-linux64-12.0_ALL.tar.xz
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ cd tor-browser/
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/tor-browser$ ls
Browser  start-tor-browser.desktop
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/tor-browser$ ./tor-browser.desktop --register-app
bash: ./tor-browser.desktop: No such file or directory
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/tor-browser$
```

Edit: I tried to install TOR following this guy's directions here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxViDkQc6xM and it keeps telling me "no such file or directory".

```
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$ ./start-tor-browser
bash: ./start-tor-browser: No such file or directory
computer@computer-System-Product-Name:~$
```

Edit: I finally got it to work!!!! So I posted over on Reddit also asking for help on this issue, and a Reddit user proposed I try

```
cd ~/Downloads/tor-browser && ./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

And whaddya know it worked like a charm!!!! I'd been working on this problem for 2 whole days straight at this point too. Here's the link to the Reddit user's comment that got it to work https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/zhqvs2/comment/izoz78g/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 make sure you click "Continue this thread" so you'll see it.

So yeah I think that what was throwing everything off was the fact they changed the typical "en-US" to simply "ALL" in the file name and I think that's what was causing the problem, I'm not sure though.

Edit: Also apparently the TOR browser launcher has a problem right now and ain't working, which explains why I couldn't get the TOR browser launcher to work. https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/659

Comment: Hello, Danny. A year ago I've tried the [Brave](https://brave.com/) browser. It is Chromium based, open source, and available for all OS. Its ad-blocker blocks even the YouTube's ads on Android. And guess what - the desktop version has built-in Tor mode :)

Comment: @pa4080 So the brave browser has TOR built in, but is it safe? Honestly I'd feel much safer just using the TOR browser itself.

Comment: Tor can run without "installation", just by downloading the archive in another browser, then extract the archive in the file manager. Why do you insist on using the terminal since you say you are a newbie?

Comment: @cipricus  I finally got it to work, I made an edit to the original post please take a look? I got the answer on Reddit.

Comment: @pa4080 I finally got it to work, I made an edit to the original post please take a look? I got the answer on Reddit. And the Brave TOR is no substitute for the TOR browser, it's not safe.

Comment: I have posted an answer that is the simplest possible. No need for you to use the terminal I think. The rule on askubuntu is to have a useful answer for future users, so you should post yourself one reflecting the reddit solution or mark as definitive one of the present ones if you like.

Comment: Upstream issues in Debian have been resolved, and Thomas (teward) now has resolved this issue on *lunar*, and SRU (*stable release update*) request for released products has been started.

Answer (score 1):

After having a look at the output, it seems you've been trying to change to a directory that doesn't exist, everything got extracted in the tor-browser/ directory, rather than tor-browser_ALL/ or tor-browser-en_US/. Although the steps you followed were recent (18 August 2022) the package downloaded has been updated 2 days ago, so it might have changed a couple things.

Edit: If you have a look at your initial output when trying to install tor using `tar`, you can see a few lines saying this:

> tor-browser/
>
> tor-browser/Browser/
>
> tor-browser/Browser/.config/
>
> and so on...

This is due to the flag -xvf, which is -x for extract, -v for verbose (this gives you additional output) and -f for determining a file (the one you just downloaded), you can find more info about this typing `tar --help`.

What does this mean? The content you just extracted is inside a new directory called `tor-browser/`. You should be able to see it typing `ls` inside the directory you downloaded the package (usually `Downloads/`) `ls` is the equivalent to `dir` in Windows.

However, having a look at your output of `sudo apt install tor` seems like tor has been already installed as you said at the bottom of the question. Try uninstalling it from the Software store or type `sudo apt autoremove --purge tor`, - after having a look at [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/420261/1652872) it's better to continue the initial installation you started.

Steps you should follow after uninstalling tor from the software store:

#1: Open a terminal

#2: Type `ls` to see the contents inside your home directory

#3: Access `Downloads/` by typing `cd Downloads/`

#4: Type `ls` again to list content inside the directory

#5: You should be able to see a directory named after `tor-browser/`, as you extracted the package before. Access it typing `cd tor-browser/`.

#6: Type `ls` to list again its content, just to make sure that `start-tor-browser.desktop` is there.

#7: Type `./tor-browser.desktop --register-app`

#8: You are done. Tor-Browser should be installed and run without errors. Check your apps.

Comment: This right here is literally the name of the downloaded file from the TOR website "tor-browser-linux64-12.0_ALL.tar.xz" Please keep in mind I'm a newbie when it comes to Linux and the terminal so be as detailed as possible. For instance you lost me here "Try changing directories to tor-browser/ and then executing ./start-tor-browser.desktop." huh? So you think the "apt update" and "apt install tor" might work, I'll give it a try? Also how do i install the necessary dependencies?

Comment: Please keep in mind that I'm a novice, I don't know how to access root in terminal and I don't even know when to insert "sudo". Because I think you assumed I knew how to do root which I don't, I was a lifelong windows user til I switched to Ubuntu. So I did what you said and I posted the results in the original post please go have a look?

Comment: @Danny It is ok to be a newbie, we've all been there at some point and I am myself when solving some more technical stuff.

Ok, sudo is used when you need root privileges, which you need sometimes when installing things if you are not using the root account, to do so you only need to type 'sudo su' and type in your password. Have in mind this is not always recommended for security reasons, just use it when necessary.

I will be updating my answer to help you on the way.

Comment: By the way, typing `sudo apt list --upgradable` will only show you those packages ready to be updated, to do so you need to type `sudo apt upgrade`. If this does nothing and says that some packages have been kept back (which happens from time to time) you can solve it with many different techniques, but I recommend `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`, if it shows an error saying that aptitude is not installed, just install it typing `sudo apt install aptitude`.

I know this is confusing, really similar names like `apt`, `apt-get` (you will see this on the internet a lot) and `aptitude`. Search info

Comment: I did what you said and posted the results in the original post, please take a look? It seems it didn't work.

Comment: I finally got it to work, I made an edit to the original post please take a look? I got the answer on Reddit.

Comment: @Cool124 Glad you finally made it to work! Have fun surfing the dark web, remember it is not a safe place to be most of the time. Also, the solution you found on reddit was pretty much the same as mine. It's not that the directory changed from en_US to ALL, that directory doesn't exist, you probably got confused with the first guide you followed. Everything got extracted in `Downloads/tor-browser/`, which is why I suggested accessing it on the steps I gave you at the end. Anyway, watch out, don't run the browser on full screen size and disable javascript, it can give away personal info about u

Answer (score 0):

Install `Tor Browser Launcher Settings`from ubuntu software.

[image]

Comment: Ok what now? Any idea why it keeps saying "no such file or directory"?

Comment: I finally got it to work, I made an edit to the original post please take a look? I got the answer on Reddit.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the answer you asked for, but I recently started using Brave, which lets you open Tor in a private window. Usually I just want to do a few things on Tor, so I'm finding this pretty convenient. Lots of other great stuff about Brave. The only thing I didn't like was the Crypto features, which [you can disable](https://www.makeuseof.com/brave-disable-crypto-features/).

Comment: Yeah I did research on Brave TOR and it's not a substitute for the TOR browser at all. But hey, I finally got it to work, I made an edit to the original post please take a look? I got the answer on Reddit.