# When I try to start TOR I get an Error 404 mesage

Tags: tor

WWhen I try to start TOR I get an Error 404 mesage . Tryed unistall and the reinstall and still get it. I have Ubuntu 22.04.01 lts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the Tor Browser Bundle in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382394/how-do-i-install-the-tor-browser-bundle-in-ubuntu)

Comment: There's a bug causing this issue... Refer https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077 though you can click the "*affects me too*" to add *heat* to that bug.  FYI:  More work has been done on that report (*mentioned in last comment on report*) but you need to look on ML to see further...