# Unable to install Tor

Tags: tor

Can anyone guide me how to install Tor in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am new here and even dont have expertise in Linux, but very much willing and excited to learn Linux. I need to install Tor anyhow on my laptop (Ubuntu). Please any help and support from anyone shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No need to install. Download the tar.gz file from [Tor website](https://www.torproject.org/download/download); extract and run the file *start-tor-browser*.

You may also want to make a .desktop file for it to easily start it from Dash or lock to Launcher. To do this, make a new text file and paste the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.0
Name=Tor Bundle
Comment=Tor browser proxy
Exec=/path/to/file/start-tor-browser
Icon=tor-browser
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;
X-Unity-IconBackgroundColor=#855e9d
```

Save the file as `tor.desktop` and move it to `~/.local/share/applications` (make one if it doesn't exist). Then go to file *Properties* and under *Permissions* tab, check *Allow executing file as program*.

Also you want an icon for it. You can save the following picture as `tor-browser` to the folder `~/.icons` – note the name is the same as what inserted for `Icon=` in the .desktop file.

[image: Tor]

To know more about .desktop files, see [the documentations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Answer (score 0):

To complement the comment linking to [How to install Tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor): just installing Tor is not enough to use it. You must also set your apps to use Tor or otherwise they will use normal Internet. The easiest option is to download [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) (if you just want to circumvent some restrictions) or [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org) (if you need 99% privacy, for example if your life may be in danger if someone finds out what do you do online).

And just using these doesn't make you invisible. You will have to change your habits too. Please read more on [Whonix wiki](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Warning).