# Tor will not launch from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity-dash, tor

I have followed all the instructions I can find. I followed instructions from [here](/q/514853/283843) to install Tor, and seemed to work fine, but now that I find the Tor icon in the dash and hit launch, it does nothing.

Tor will not launch from dash, what now?
When I used Tor in W7 it worked fine, but now that I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)

Answer (score 0):

Tor can be launched from the dash. The usual problem is that the path to "start-tor-browser" is messed up. Check the command line under "properties" to see if it is correct. If this doesn't work and you used the Tor Browser Bundle, check your download to be sure that you actually decompressed all your files. Find and click the "start-tor-browser" file. If Tor does not start, something is still compressed. When you can start the program from this file, your problem is in linking to the launcher properly.