# Mask ip on ubuntu

Tags: ip, localhost, static-ip

I wat to mask my ubuntu station in the following way:I am having an internet connection with dynamic ip (PPPoE).I want to make some static ip and dns over that connection and use them when I go out.I must say that I am interested in some approaches simmilar with what I just described, not to use open VPN, and proxys .Any suggestion will be highly appreciated .

Comment: Well then your only real option is Tor I guess...?

Comment: Hi tnks  for  your rapid  feedback .Tor  does not  realy help me , cause I  need to have  my ip static  so my egine application  could  connect  somewhere   in  high frequent manner like in trading.

Comment: Why do you not what any of the others? And why do you need IP masking?

Comment: I am  making  something  like  my on trading stuff and  some pages   are blocked from  my provider that is all.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a network endpoint with a static IP that traverses your dynamically addressed network that doesn't involve some sort of VPN or proxy.

Comment: What does Tor come under then?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand OP's question, but if you want to have your traffic always exiting via the same IP address, then Tor is the opposite of what you need. Tor routes your traffic through different exit nodes all the time, so you'll never keep the same exit IP address.

Comment: He wants to mask his IP, no? *Edit:* Oh, I see, he also wants it's static. My bad.

Comment: @Tim When I read "I want to make some static ip and dns over that connection" I assumed he meant he wanted his traffic to reach the internet via a statically IP addressed server somewhere.

Comment: Yes , that  was  exatly what I  wanted .

Comment: @georgemilitaru then you need a VPN or Proxy.

Comment: I   was thinking  if  I could  do something else  without proxy,  please see my bellow  message, I was thinking  if I could make  a little private station on current one  and exit with that ip