# installing tor on ubuntu 14.04 using debuild

Tags: package-management, permissions, tor, debuild

I'm trying to install tor on my system, I've followed the steps on the tor projects site entirely and I've ran into an issue on this step

```
$ mkdir ~/debian-packages; cd ~/debian-packages
$ apt-get source tor
$ cd tor-*
$ debuild -rfakeroot -uc -us
$ cd ..
```

When I ran `$ debuild -rfakeroot -uc -us` I got

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package tor
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.2.8.7-1~trusty+1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty-backport
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by jenkins role account <jenkins@build-x86-    03.torproject.org>
dpkg-source --before-build tor-0.2.8.7
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh \
    clean \
    --with quilt \
    --with autoreconf \
     \
    --builddirectory=build \
    --parallel
dh_testdir -O--builddirectory=build -O--parallel
dh_auto_clean -O--builddirectory=build -O--parallel
dh_quilt_unpatch -O--builddirectory=build -O--parallel
No patch removed
dh_quilt_unpatch: failed to write to debian/tor.debhelper.log: Permission denied
END failed--call queue aborted.
make: *** [clean] Error 13
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

What is wrong here and how should I proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Tor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor)

Comment: this is focusing on a specific part of the installation im having trouble with

Comment: There is no need to compile it from source.

Comment: at the top of the instructions on the tors site it says the ubuntu's universe has not been reliably  updated so i figured from the source would be better, but i think i just figured it out, just forgot to run it as super user lol

Comment: There are very clear instructions at https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en for how to get Tor that is more updated than the one in the official repo. Did you try that yet? I fail to see a need to compile from source. Even if you did compile from source successfully, note that you have to repeat the compilation every time the source gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you download the source package from the official Ubuntu repositories and build it manually instead of simply installing the binary package from there? If you fetch the source package from the Ubuntu repository, it will be the exactly same version as the binary package.

Just install it the normal way:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

Comment: And `tor` package is not `tor-browser`.

Comment: like i told pilot, the tor project doesn't recommend downloading from the ubuntu repositories because they havent always been reliably updated so i'd rather go through the source but i think i got it just by running with sudo

Comment: i just figured after install the tor package i would download the browser and launcher, i just want to make sure i'm going through the source to ensure i have the correct and most up to date software

Comment: @thedude But when you run `apt-get source tor` you get the sources from the Ubuntu repository! Those are the same sources from which the binary package in the repository is built. If you need more up too date sources, you have to get them somewhere else.

Comment: then why does the tor project's page say this    "Do not use the packages in Ubuntu's universe. In the past they have not reliably been updated. That means you could be missing stability and security fixes."

Comment: Do you have a link to where exactly they state that? However, as I said, the `apt-get source` command retrieves the source from the Ubuntu repository. If the binary package there is outdated, the source package is as well. You would have to retrieve the source from the developers website or GitHub or wherever they host it.