# Tor browser installation hangs on verifying signature

Tags: tor

I followed [instructions](https://itsfoss.com/install-tar-browser-linux/), but after clicking the Tor Browser Icon the process hangs on 'verifying signatures'.
Is there any way out to install tor browser?

Comment: duplicate:https://askubuntu.com/questions/881082/tor-installation-error-signature-verification-failed

Comment: Anyway that question is protected by community and I wanted to share my knowledge. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

The thing that hangs is `gpg`. Run `ps -ef | grep gpg` while tor is verifying signatures and see there's actually a `gpg` running.
Tor browser installer will run `gpg --refresh-keys` anyways, so (from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/cn30lj/tor_browser_stuck_at_verifying_signature_while/))

> Because of [some jerk on the internet poisoning PGP keys](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2019/07/14/mitigating-poisoned-pgp-certificates/), downloading and using the TB developers' poisoned key will take forever

But we don't need to follow the link to cure the gpg db, as it has another home directory. We just need to download and install the 'poisoned' key safely.
This thing is implemented in [`gpg 2.2.17`](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4591#127744) and later versions. So you **need to** `/usr/bin/gpg --version` and **update** `gpg` if it's older than **`2.2.17`**.
The update process is rather simple, too: get to this [git gist](https://gist.github.com/vt0r/a2f8c0bcb1400131ff51), load the script, replace `2.2.10` with `2.2.17` within the script and run download, compilation and make.
Maybe you should copy `/usr/local/bin/gpg*` over `/usr/bin/gpg*` after it.
Enjoy )

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17
libgcrypt 1.8.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```