# Lost with downloading tor/running tor in ubuntu

Tags: tor

Please be gentle as I am brand new to linux and ubuntu!

I have been trying to get this to work the the last hour.

I tried every suggestion I found online, multiple ways of downloading, etc.

I am trying to download tor in ubuntu. First i followed the instructions here:

https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

I ran $ apt-get install tor

It is now telling me that I have the most recent version of Tor but I cannot find it anywhere in the dashboard when I search for it.

Next I downloaded it from here:

https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Now when I extract it I see a file called start-tor-browser.desktop

However when i click on it it takes me to a text file. I have my preferences set to run executable text files when they are opened and it hasn't changed anything.

Any help would really be appreciated, I really want to like ubuntu but I am already getting frustrated.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. I moved the download to my desktop and opened it there. Thank you anyway! Mods please close this I guess unless it can help somebody else!

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 16.04 or later you should try installing [torbrowser-launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/how-to-install-tor/873767#873767) from the default Ubuntu repositories. It's better because it's self-updating.