# For every tarball I've ever tried to install from, I get bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, tor

I have had 3 Ubuntu computers in my (relatively short) linux lifetime. On every single one, I have never been able to install from a tarball. I've looked everywhere, but there seems to always be a different answer depending on what you're trying to install, and not always one for what I'm working with. This time, I'm trying to install tor and hoping for a different result, but lo and behold I get:

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory.`

I just want an end-all answer as to why on every single Ubuntu machine I've had, I can't configure/install from a tarball.

Edit: the tarball I was trying to install from is the 64 bit linux download from https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads , and the only readmes in there are explanations of meek, proxies, etc. Nothing about install. I figured out Tor specifically though by not using ./configure at all, so that's done.

But the main problem is that I have never successfully installed from a tar file. No matter what I try to install, when I get to the ./configure step, I get a bash message.

Comment: Is there a README or INSTALL document in the tarball? What does it say the procedure is? Not every tarball package uses `./configure` in the compile process. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: give us a specific tarball link, and you'll have a better answer

Comment: Sounds like there is no file named `configure` in the directory you're currently in...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6522/). Tor Browser can be installed from Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

Comment: ***The instructions*** on the page you mention (https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads) ***don't mention `configure` at all***. Instead they say **1)** Download the tarball, **2)** unpack the tarball, **3)** issue `cd tor-browser_LANG`, **4)** issue `./start-tor-browser.desktop`. There is nothing to configure or compile. The tarfile contains _tor_ ready-to-run. Just scroll down to _"Linux Instructions"_. Please read the instructions on the page you got that software from before running arbitrary commands and starting to wonder why they don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some reasons I can think of:

1. the tarball doesn't contain source code
2. the tarball contains source code, but it doesn't use the [GNU autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html) build system - perhaps it uses a simple `Makefile`, or uses a different build system such as [cmake](https://cmake.org/) or [scons](https://scons.org/)
3. the tarball is a source tarball that uses the GNU autotools build system, but it provides a lower-level configuration file such as `configure.ac` from which you must first build an appropriate `configure` script for your platform using `autoconf`
4. the tarball is a source tarball, including a GNU autotools `configure` script, but you're attempting to execute it from the wrong directory

Comment: Good guesses. Correct is [1]. ;-)